# What is the most future-proof way to perform Java bytecode instrumentation?

Tags: java

I wish to perform Java bytecode instrumentation from JDK 1.5 onwards. Is there a way to do this that works across most JVMs and is supported in future versions of the JDK?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to guarantee future compatability simply because there is no way to know what they might change. Just wanted to point that out. But we can assume there will not be any major changes to most bytecode coding.

Comment: But what would be a good bet for a way to do this that works with current JDKs at least?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a library which abstracts away the reading/writing of raw byte code. Like ASM.  This way any future changes may be fixed by updating the library.  Also many of these have gone through many version changes already and have a structure which is farily version proof.

Having said that, there are very few byte code changes between JVM versions.  Given the chance to change the byte code or to put in work around, the later appears to always be used. e.g. Java has supported inner classes accessing private member of outer classes for *many* years, however the JVM doesn't support this directly (instead a work around is used by the compiler)

Comment: Do any such libraries exist on top of ASM?

Comment: I would say ASM has libraries which exist on top of its core library.  Have you looked at ASM to see if it is suitable?

Comment: I looked at ASM but it is far too low level

Comment: If you want to see the byte code, you need to look at the low level.  Another approach is to use AOP. e.g. AspectJ.  This is a higher level library which allows you to inject Java code, perhaps this is more suitable.